# Python: "FOR" loop to print lines based column fields match

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, linux, csv

I have python code which generates list of lines from a raw file, and I want to search specific column field [4th column field with for lines having IT in second field, 5th Column field for lines having FW.O in second fields] and match from external file content fields, and print lines.

```
L = '''SET,FW.O,AS,num:+18700000,num:+12355,
SET,IT,AS,num:+22211111,num:+12355,
SET,FW.O,AS,num:+177232,num:+12355,
SET,IT,AS,num:+368399793,num:+12355,
'''.split()

FWmatch = open("fwfields.txt").readlines()
ITmatch = open("itfields.txt").readlines()
for row in L:
      if row[1] == "IT":
          result = [i for i in L if any(x.replace('\n','') in i.split(',')[3] for x in ITmatch)]
      elif row[1] == "FW.O":
          result = [i for i in L if any(x.replace('\n','') in i.split(',')[4] for x in FWmatch)]
print('\n'.join(result))
```

if "L" 2nd col field is "IT", `ITmatch` should lookup at 5th column field.

if "L" 2nd col field is "FW.O" `FWmatch` should lookup at 5th column field.

`cat fwfields.txt`

```
num:+12
num:+123
```

`cat itfields.txt`

```
num:+222
num:+333
```

Getting error as as "output" not defined, since my code not working, and variable output is not defined.. Getting IndexError if I remove .split() at "L".
Required output:

```
SET,FW.O,AS,num:+18700000,num:+12355,#(5th field matched with FWmatch num:+123)
SET,IT,AS,num:+22211111,num:+12355,#(4th field matched with ITmatch num:+222)
SET,FW.O,AS,num:+177232,num:+12355,#(5th field matched with FWmatch num:+123)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails because `result` was not initialized, and the condition never holds, because row[1] is the first character of row. You should use row.split(',')[1] instead. Here's a code that works:

```
L = '''SET,FW.O,AS,num:+18700000,num:+12355,
SET,IT,AS,num:+22211111,num:+12355,
SET,FW.O,AS,num:+177232,num:+12355,
SET,IT,AS,num:+368399793,num:+12355,
'''.split()

def chomp(x):
    return x.replace('\n','')

FWmatch = open("fwfields.txt").readlines()
ITmatch = open("itfields.txt").readlines()
result=[]
for row in L:
      country = row.split(',')[1]
      if country == "IT":
          codes = ITmatch
      elif country == "FW.O":
          codes = FWmatch
      num = row.split(',')[3]
      if any(chomp(c) in num for c in codes):
          result.append( row)
print('\n'.join(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat fwfields.txt
num:+17
num:+18`

$ cat itfields.txt
num:+222
num:+333

lines="""SET,FW.O,AS,num:+18700000,num:+12355,
SET,IT,AS,num:+22211111,num:+12355,
SET,FW.O,AS,num:+177232,num:+12355,
SET,IT,AS,num:+368399793,num:+12355,
""".split()

def chomp(x):
    return x.replace('\n','')
```

points to consider:

1. remove endline from each line
2. you cannot 'reuse' open, as it reads the file through. Need to read it to a list which you can later use multiple times.

This works:

```
FWmatch = open("fwfields.txt").readlines()
ITmatch = open("itfields.txt").readlines()
result1 = [i for i in lines if any(chomp(x) in i for x in FWmatch)]
result2 = [i for i in lines if any(chomp(x) in i for x in ITmatch)]
print('\n'.join(result1+result2))
```

This don't:

```
FWmatch = open("fwfields.txt")
ITmatch = open("itfields.txt")
result1 = [i for i in lines if any(chomp(x) in i for x in FWmatch.readlines())]
result2 = [i for i in lines if any(chomp(x) in i for x in ITmatch.readlines())]
print('\n'.join(result1+result2))
```

Comment: Hi, I have redefined my question to have more clarity.. result1, result2 works fine for me, but I want to use FOR loop to read each line, and to see it second field is IT or FW.O, and if satisfied, match 4th/5th column from required ITmatch/FWmatch files.. please see the FOR loop, IF..ELSE condition I have tried, and help for to understand error problem.